# Paste and repeat a character value number of time specified by the column and create a new column in r

Tags: r

I have df   I would like to create a new column that is code repeated by frequency concatenated by and underscore
if frequency is 3 and code is 1003 output would be "1003_1003_1003"

```
df<-data.frame( "userid" = stri_rand_strings(5,12), "code" = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"), "frequency" = seq.int(1:30) )
```

```
head(df)
        userid: code frequency
1 FVddk0XxpgWf 1001         1
2 DDOn4sz4ndwk 1002         2
3 Mzhy6JdXHQSj 1003         3
4 eHFd8BCO9L4A 1004         4
5 nyl9BADGmlun 1005         5
6 FVddk0XxpgWf 1001         6
```

I would like to  have code pasted by the number of times show in frequency separated by an underscore in a new column...so row 2 would have the new_column = "1002_1002"

I have tried :

```
df$new_column<-paste(rep(df$code, df$frequency), sep  = "_"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, `strrep` could be used

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     mutate(new_column = trimws(strrep(str_c(code, "_"),
          frequency), whitespace = "_"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`strrep` option by @akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66960338/12158757) is very efficient. Here is another option with base R

```
transform(
  df,
  new = mapply(function(x, y) paste0(rep(x, y), collapse = "_"), code, frequency)
)
```

or `tapply` (thank @akrun's comment)

```
within(
  df,
  new = tapply(rep(code, frequency), rep(seq_along(code), frequency), FUN = paste, collapse = "_")
)
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot! Added!